# Run Maven goal for only one module in multi module project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a project which has 4 modules. That said, I have a parent project with a parent POM.xml specifying theses modules.

```
<modules>
        <module>Module1-Desktop</module>
        <module>Module2-Core</module>
        <module>Module3-Web</module>
        <module>Module4-EAR</module>
</modules>
```

The **Module4-EAR** has **Module3-Web** and **Module2-Core** as dependencies (not as modules) and generates an EAR to be deployed to JBoss.

I want to be able to build the **Module4-EAR**, but building **Module3-Web** and **Module2-Core** before it, so it is up-to-date and also deploy it to JBoss. So I'm running the following Maven command in the parent project:

```
mvn --projects Module2-Core,Module3-Web,Module4-EAR clean install jboss:hard-undeploy jboss:hard-deploy
```

In the parent POM I've set the jboss-maven-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>                   
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

In the Module4-EAR's pom.xml I've set the jboss-maven-plugin this way:

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <jbossHome>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</jbossHome>
                            <serverName>default</serverName>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <fileNames>
                                <fileName>build/Module4-EAR.ear</fileName>
                            </fileNames>                            
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

The problem is that I want only the **Module4-EAR.ear** to be deployed with to the server, but the **Module3-Web.war** and **Module2-Core** are deployed as well. I want to do it in a single command, instead of running 2 mvn commands, one to "clean install" the projects and another to deploy only the EAR. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to deploy the ear then add the jboss-maven-plugin into the pom of Module4-EAR. So the plugin will only work within that module. Adding deployment plugins into a parent pom often leads to executing it into all modules - which is often not what you want.

You can chain the commands so a `mvn clean install plugin:goal`

The plugin you use seems to be superceded by JBoss AS7 Deployment Plugin: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/ (as a side note)

So it would look like `mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy`

You can also add an execution to the jboss plugin and bind it to the deploy phase so a `mvn clean deploy` would copy the artifact into a remote repository and deploy the ear into jboss.

An example using the install phase is at: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html

Comment: Removing the jboss-maven-plugin from the parent doesn't work. It still executes the jboss-maven-plugin for all projects, instead of only the last one.

Comment: is there another parent pom in your project? because plugins that are not configured do not run. Can you execute a "mvn help:effective-pom" in those modules that are not supposed to have that plugin and check if it's actually true? The config may also come from a profile in settings.xml

Comment: Yes, there is another parent pom. I've solved the problem and I'm posting the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add this to the only project that I want to execute the jboss:hard-deploy.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <jbossHome>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</jbossHome>
                    <serverName>default</serverName>
                    <unpack>true</unpack>
                    <fileNames>
                        <fileName>build/cadprev-web-ear-1.0.0.ear</fileName>
                    </fileNames>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>hard-deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

Removed the code below from the parent POM.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>                   
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And changed the mvn command to:

```
mvn --projects Module2-Core,Module3-Web,Module4-EAR clean install
```